# ruby on rails sum fields after group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

before I start I just want to tell that I tried some aproaches from similar topics but they don't work well with my case.

I have orders that I am grouping by days (using group_by(&:created_at) method). Now I want to sum "total" field from orders that are on particular days. It should look something like that:
21 May 2015
Total: 215 (order1 with total = 200 and order2 with total = 15)
22 May 2015
Total: 0
23 May 2015
Total: 321

I tried something like this

```
orders.to_a.map { |h| h[:total] }.sum 
orders.to_a.inject { |sum, h| sum += h[:total] }
```

but it prints me only totals from each order (not daily sum).

I am fetching data from database (postgres) like this:

```
  @orders = current_user.orders.where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month.. Time.now).group_by(&:created_at)
```

And I'm getting something like this as a result:

```
    {Sat, 06 Jun 2015 13:06:08 CEST +02:00=>
[#<Order id: 19, total:10], 
[#<Order id: 20, total:12], 
Fri, 05 Jun 2015 15:42:24 CEST +02:00=>
[#<Order id: 19, total:10], 
[#<Order id: 20, total:12]}
```

@pauloancheta
Using your solution and having view like this (HAML)

```
#subtotal
  - @orders.each do |day,orders|
    .col-md-4
      %h2
        = day.strftime("%Y  %m %d")
        = link_to '', monthly_summary_path(date: day), class: "btn btn-info btn-small glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"
      %p= "sum: #{orders.map(&:total).sum}"
```

When I have two orders in one day i get two separate columns instead of 1 with sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `created_at` is a timestamp not a date so you're not grouping by dates at all, you're grouping by date *and* time of day. This is why you'll get multiple results for some dates.

Secondly, you can get the database to do all the work by using a GROUP BY on the date and then summing the `total` within each group:

```
current_user.orders
            .where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month .. Time.now)
            .group('created_at::date')
            .sum(:total)
```

That will give you a Hash like this:

```
{ date_object => sum_for_that_date, ... }
```

Comment: Thank you! I got confused with "created_at" because when i checked it's class it has "ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone". I've tried to use the sum before but with bad "group".

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with my console and it worked. Hope it would work for you as well. `orders.map(&:total).sum`

`Order.where` already returns an array so I think there is no need for a `.to_a` method.